# Android Dynamic Grid with different items number

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm new to Android, and what I want to achieve is something like this [gridLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sbg9.png)

As you can see on the picture, I want to build a grid with a **dynamic number of columns**, each having a **dynamic number of rows** and a different number of items for each column.

So far I ve been able to create a grid with a RelativeLayout, following tutorials like this one :
[link to tutorial](https://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76)

But how to get items to be added vertically and not horizontally...?

Any help/ documentation/ start point would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest checkout out the documentation at https://d.android.com. Specifically look at the APIs for GridView to see if there is something useful to do what you want.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I will check this out !

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm, a few hours later, answering my own question :)

I've come out with a linearLayout filled with ListViews !

Here is my view :

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearCategoryLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp">
        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/categoryListView"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
                android:listSelector="#00BCD4"
                />
        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/categoryListView2"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
                android:listSelector="#00BCD4"/>
        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/categoryListView3"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
                android:listSelector="#00BCD4"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

next, I will progamatically be addind my listViews, and that will do the trick !